# Magento2.1 ui grid, remove or clear filter issue (after removing filter, result row apply to whole collection)

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, grid, order-grid

I created ui grid in magento 2.1.0 and facing issue while removing filters or clear all filters from ui grid. My filtered result occupies whole grid means **same row repeated in the whole grid** after removing filter.

I figure out why this issue arise, but unable to fix this issue.

Issue arise due to **mui/index/render** get request does not fire while removing filter or clear all filter.

In fact it worked when 2 or more filters are applied and I remove them but not in case of last filtered applied.

Comment: This is happening due to special caching for 1st active appilied filter.Please give me any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just to add to the previous solution [by Tony Bartiloro](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/131725/31734). The specific fix is to add the 'storageConfig' item. If this is missing you will see the issue where row data is duplicated.

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
</item>
```

Where 'entity_id' is your primary key for the collection data, and also the same as defined in

```
<argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
```

And the following can be removed completely. As this is just duplicating the value specified already in the 'dataProvider' node.

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: yes you are right , its working now

Comment: Cheers to your solution :) +1 from me

Answer (score 18):

i had same issue and I resolve with this code in ui_component xml:

```
<dataSource name="storelocator_store_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">StoreGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">storelocator_store_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Take a look at node name "DataProvider".
Hope it helps

Comment: Yes , it worked great , Thanks a lot tony :)

Comment: thanks @Tony u have saved my time working perfect so +vote

Answer (score 12):

I've got the same issue on **Magento 2.3** and resolved by using the following code in `ui_component.xml`.

```
<dataSource component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider" name="listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">primary_id</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        ...
        ...
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you fixed that?

Comment: @SandervanZuidam from admin grid's ui_component.xml file

Comment: @Aasim Goriya, Me also got same issue, added your code. Now filters working fine. Thank you, you saved my time.

Comment: Have an idea about how to apply default filter in ui grid?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh what do you mean by default filter? can you please explain more?

Comment: Like: On-grid load, sees only enable row and if I clear/reset filter then display all value.

Comment: @AasimGoriya Any idea?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh ok so your issue is when you reset the filter your grid doesn't show all values correct?

Comment: No, I want to set apply default filter on grid load.

Comment: @DhadukMitesh I don't think this can be possible, as Magento's grid data save in ui_bookmark table and when you filter the data will save in ui_bookmark so it can't be possible to reset filter until data change in ui_bookmark table, so you need to remove ui_bookmark table entries while your page load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102526/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-aasim-goriya).

Comment: How to modify the extended sales order grid in Magento 2?

Comment: thanks more to  you

Answer (score 0):

In your ui_component listing.xml file, find

```
<dataSource component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider"
```

Add / Update it by below code

```
<dataSource component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider" name="......_listing_data_source">
    <settings>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">primary_key_id_here</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>......</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" name="......_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>primary_key_id_here</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
```

In short, add `<storageConfig>` tag in `<dataSource>`